# Disabling /cloudfoundryapplication in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcf

I set `management.cloudfoundry.enabled=false` in my spring boot application.properties file and deployed my app on PCF. However, I still see the endpoint being invoked. What else is needed to avoid the invocation of that endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop it. When your application is deployed to Pivotal Cloud Foundry, Apps Manager will query that endpoint. It does this to be able to display additional information about your application.

In older versions of Apps Manager it would query your app whenever it needed the info. In newer versions of Apps Manager it is smarter and will back off if it get's a non-200 HTTP response code, like if you've disabled the endpoint or if you have a non-Spring app that doesn't implement the endpoint. Even in these newer versions, you'll still see it generating some of these requests, there just won't be nearly as many.

Do note that if you set `management.cloudfoundry.enabled=false`, Apps Manager won't be able to display all the additional Spring & Java related information.

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-2/console/using-actuators.html